# use fork to execute a python function defined in the same script

Tags: python, fork

My python function would be like below format.

```
def f1():
 <function code>
def f2():
 <function code>
while True:
 if(first condition success):
 f1()
 if(second condition success):
 f2()
 time.sleep(60)
```

In the infinite loop I wanted to implement `fork()` and execute the functions in `parallel` on separate threads if the condition succeeds. Presently the functions execute one after the other when both the conditions succeed.
My expected code would be similar to

```
while True:
 if(first condition success):
 #os.fork() execute only f1()
 if(second condition success):
 #os.fork() execute only f1()
 time.sleep(60)
```

Comment: What is the point of the condition if you want them both to do the same thing?

Comment: Both functions are different and the conditions executing them also different. Presently it runs one after the other and wanted fork to gain parallelism and should be executed on a different pid for other business case